# Image is loading as null

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am new to javascript but I am trying to have the default image set with the onload() and I don't think that it is reaching the image that I set up in the array and I cannot figure out why.

I am going to have it rotate images after I click on the button but I can't even get the default image to add.

```
var images = ['img/profile.jpg', 'img/mountain.jpg', 'img/sanfran.jpg'];
var num=1;

function loadPage()
{
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0].src;
}

function nextImage(pictures)
{
    var img = document.getElementById("pictures");
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[1].src;
    console.log(num++); // I have this just to make sure that it is catching something
}

<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="pictures">
     <img src="img/mountain.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <p>
    </p>
    <button onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When do you call function `loadPage`?

Comment: Moreover, images is an array and when you are trying to access `images[0].src` it will be undefined as it is an array of strings and not objects..

Comment: On the body tag. I would have put that there but the HTML would have been too large

Comment: you are trying to add `src` to `div` with id `pictures `. Add id to `img` tag

Comment: I have updated your code and removed some bugs please check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have your id="pictures" on the image tag, not the div.
Like this:

```
<img id="pictures" src="img/mountain.jpg">
```

Also leave off the .src in loadPage() and nextImage()

```
document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here images is an javascript array. So you cannot use .src as it is not an HTML img element

```js
var images = ['img/profile.jpg', 'img/mountain.jpg', 'img/sanfran.jpg'];
var num=1;

//This function will run on body onload
function loadPage()
{
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0];
}

//This function will run on button click
function nextImage()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("pictures");
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[1];
    console.log(num++); // I have this just to make sure that it is catching something
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadPage()">
 <div id="maincontent">
  <img id="pictures" src="img/mountain.jpg">
  <div id="paragraph">
   <p>
   </p>
   <button onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
<script>
var images = ['img/profile.jpg', 'img/mountain.jpg', 'img/sanfran.jpg'];
var num=0;

function loadPage()
{
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0].src;
}

function nextImage(pictures)
{
    if(num<images.length-1) {
     num = num+1;
 } else {
 num = 0;
 }

    var img = document.getElementById("pictures");
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[num];
    console.log(num); // I have this just to make sure that it is catching something
}
</script>
```

```html
<div onload="loadPage()">
  <div id="imageholder">
     <img id="pictures" src="img/mountain.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <p>
    </p>
    <button onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code please check.

```js
var images = ['img/profile.jpg', 'img/mountain.jpg', 'img/sanfran.jpg'];
var num=0;

loadPage();
function loadPage()
{
    console.log(num);
    document.getElementById("picture").src = images[num];
    num++;
}

function nextImage(pictures)
{
    if(typeof images[num] === 'undefined') {
      // does not exist
      num = 0;
    }
    console.log(num);
    document.getElementById("picture").src = images[num];    
    num++;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="pictures">
     <img src="img/mountain.jpg" id="picture">
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <p>
    </p>
    <button onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
</div>
```